# WCF 4.5 and Soap UI with x509 certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate

I am new to WCF and I can get a .net client app to talk to my WCF web service with a certificate but I cannot get a NON WCF app such as Soap UI 5.0 to work.  I am using a self signed certificate for testing but I get the following error.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
     </s:Reason>
  </s:Fault>
```

I have setup SOAP UI based on this article https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Help-with-Certificate/td-p/41385

This is my web config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
          algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding_https" messageEncoding="Text">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
          algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors" name="OneService4.OneServiceWCF">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" name="OneService" contract="OneService4.IOneServiceWCF" />
    <endpoint address="m" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding_https" name="OneServiceHttps" contract="OneService4.IOneServiceWCF" />
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="mex2" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors" >
      <serviceSecurityAudit  auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true"  />
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="https" port="443" />
          <add scheme="http" port="80" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <serviceCredentials>
           <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your web.config, the service security audit has already been enabled. You can get more details in the EventLogs. (Open you Event Viewer, and open the corresponding Application folder for why the security error happened). You can then trouble shoot the issue that actually cause the security error.

It could be caused by the mismatch between you security binding and SOAPUI hash algorithm.